# How to resize image in Drupal 7?

Tags: image, drupal-7

I'm working on Drupal 7.

Drupal 7 has inbuilt function image_load() & image_resize(). But it not resizing image. Although it has not source folder & destination folder path.

Can anybody help on this?

Answer (score 0):

Try using [theme_image_formatter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!image!image.field.inc/function/theme_image_formatter/7)() ?!

Answer (score 0):

You have to use

```
image_save(stdClass $image, $destination = NULL) after image_resize().
```

See [Drupal API](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21image.inc/function/image_save/7).

Answer (score 0):

```
function mymodulename_file_presave ($file) {

    if($file->type=='image')
    {
       $image_file = $file->uri;
       $image_name= $file->filename;
       $file_full_url= file_create_url($image_file); 
       $url = $image_file;
       $destination_folder =$image_file;
       $newfname =  $destination_folder;

        if($file->filemime=='image/jpeg')
        {
            $file = fopen ($url, "rb");
            if ($file) 
            {
                $filename=$newfname;
                $img = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);
                header("Content-Type: image/jpeg");
                imagejpeg($img, $filename, 50);
            }
            if ($file) 
            {
                fclose($file);
            }
        }
        else if($file->filemime=='image/png')
        {
             $file = fopen ($url, "rb");
            if ($file) 
            {
                $filename=$newfname;
                $img = imagecreatefrompng($filename);
                header("Content-Type: image/jpeg");
                imagejpeg($img, $filename, 50);
            }
            if ($file) 
            {
                fclose($file);
            }
        }
        else if($file->filemime=='image/gif')
        {
            $file = fopen ($url, "rb");
            if ($file) 
            {
                $filename=$newfname;
                $img = imagecreatefrompng($filename);
                header("Content-Type: image/jpeg");
                imagejpeg($img, $filename, 50);
            }
            if ($file) 
            {
                fclose($file);
            }
        }
    }
```